# Override the [Authorize(Roles = "xxx")]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorize

I have an API controller

```
[ApiController]
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Get1()
    {}

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Get2()
    {}

    [Authorize(Role="xxx")]
    public ActionResult Get3()
    {}
}
```

In my Startup I've specified:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().AddRequirements(new DataRequirement()).Build();
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().AddRequirements(new DataRequirement()).Build();
});
```

Which takes care of the `Get1` (fallback) and `Get2` (default).

But how can I customize a Policy handling this decoration `[Authorize(Role="xxx")]`?

I actually don't want to use the `Role`-parameter, but rather something like `[Authorize(RoleSuffix="_yyy")]` coz I can't enter the full AdGroup name, only the last part. And that's why I need to customize this.

Requirements:

- I don't want to use a FilterAttribute, which works great eg: `[DoAuthorize("_xxx")]`
- I can't change in AD and put groups in groups etc

The closest thing I've come up with is to specify a Policy in the decoration `[Authorize(Policy = "policy")]` but how can I specify a suffix-parameter to this policy? I don't want to create 1 policy per suffix. I would like to specify the suffix at the method.

The reason I need to customize a lot here: I have a few special groups that should have access to everything, and a few based on the group's suffix, and one basic default for methods with no suffix specified.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Parameterized authorize attribute example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-7.0#parameterized-authorize-attribute-example).

Here is an example of how you can implement this for your scenario:

```cs
public class SuffixAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    const string POLICY_PREFIX = "RoleSuffix";

    public SuffixAuthorizeAttribute(string suffix) => Suffix = suffix;

    public string Suffix
    {
        get
        {
            return Policy == null ? string.Empty : Policy[POLICY_PREFIX.Length..];
        }
        set
        {
            Policy = $"{POLICY_PREFIX}{value}";
        }
    }
}

public class SuffixPolicyProvider : IAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{
    const string POLICY_PREFIX = "RoleSuffix";

    private DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider BackupPolicyProvider { get; }

    public SuffixPolicyProvider(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options)
    {
        BackupPolicyProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider(options);
    }

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetDefaultPolicyAsync()
        => BackupPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync();

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy?> GetFallbackPolicyAsync()
        => BackupPolicyProvider.GetFallbackPolicyAsync();

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy?> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        if (policyName.StartsWith(POLICY_PREFIX, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var suffix = policyName[POLICY_PREFIX.Length..];

            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();

            policy.RequireAssertion(
              context => context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && c.Value.EndsWith(suffix)));

            return Task.FromResult(policy?.Build());
        }

        return BackupPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);
    }
}
```

Register the custom `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, SuffixPolicyProvider>();
```

Use like this:

```cs
[SuffixAuthorize("_yyy")]
public ActionResult Get3()
{
}
```

this is the equivalent of doing: `[Authorize(Policy = "RoleSuffix_yyy")]`. Only difference is you don't have to create a policy for each suffix because the policy is created "dynamically" from the custom `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider`.

Comment: This is very cool, thank you so much @Dimitris. I'm totally gonna use this in my situation. It's kind of weird to transfer the metadata (role name) via the policy name but as you wrote I'm not sure it can't be done in another way. The AuthorizeAttribute has a ROLE field but I don't think you can get that value in the IAuthorizationPolicyProvider. Thank you!